# QTimeEdit How to increment to next hour when minutes are incremented?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having a `QTimeEdit` displaying `hh:mm`.

This widget behavior is very annoying: When the value is `09:59`, there is no easy way to move to `10:00`. The spinbox controls on the right only applies to minutes or hours. When you put your cursor on minutes, incrementing is not allowed if value is `59`.

To move from `09:59` to `10:00` you need to decrement `59` to `00` and then increment `09` to `10`...that's really annoying.

Is there no option to make it possible to let user increment minutes by one using the spinbox control and then get value be changed from `09:59` to `10:00` with a single click??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [wrapping](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#wrapping-prop) to `true`.

As for the automatic change of the hours section, reimplement `stepBy` in a subclass of *QTimeEdit* like this:

**MyTimeEdit.h**

```
#ifndef MYTIMEEDIT_H
#define MYTIMEEDIT_H

#include <QTimeEdit>

class MyTimeEdit : public QTimeEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTimeEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void stepBy(int steps) override;
};

#endif // MYTIMEEDIT_H
```

**MyTimeEdit.cpp**

```
#include "MyTimeEdit.h"

MyTimeEdit::MyTimeEdit(QWidget *parent) : QTimeEdit(parent)
{
    setWrapping(true);
}

void MyTimeEdit::stepBy(int steps)
{
    QTime cur = time();

    QTimeEdit::stepBy(steps);

    if (currentSection() == QDateTimeEdit::MinuteSection) {
        int m = cur.minute();
        if ((m == 0) && (steps < 0))
            setTime(time().addSecs(-3600));
        else if ((m == 59) && (steps > 0))
            setTime(time().addSecs(3600));
    }
    else if (currentSection() == QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection) {
        int s = cur.second();
        if ((s == 0) && (steps < 0))
            setTime(time().addSecs(-60));
        else if ((s == 59) && (steps > 0))
            setTime(time().addSecs(60));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! It's a shame we have to write all this code. Specially if you also want this to work with seconds....and even more if you want this to work smartly with `QDateTimeEdit` (where you may want to increment days automatically after midnight)...

Comment: @jpo38, I totally agree with you. This should be a built-in functionality.

Comment: Added seconds incrementation/decrementation support to your answer ;-)

Comment: @jpo38 Great addition. Thank you!

Comment: @jpo38, I've voted up the issue in JIRA. Let's hope they imrpove it in the next release.

Comment: @jpo38, since the last time we've talked about this I've decided to create a [free and open-source library of custom widgets](https://github.com/scopchanov/flat-gui) and now I would like to share it. You might find it useful, as it contains a date and time pickers too.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the above answer does not work when using the mouse wheel or Page Up/Page Down instead of the arrow keys, because then the step is larger than 1 (10 in my case).

Here is a version of MyTimeEdit.cpp that also works with the mouse wheel and Page Up/Down keys:

**MyTimeEdit.cpp**

```
#include "MyTimeEdit.h"

MyTimeEdit::MyTimeEdit(QWidget *parent) : QTimeEdit(parent)
{
    setWrapping(true);
}

void MyTimeEdit::stepBy(int steps)
{
    if (currentSection() == QDateTimeEdit::MinuteSection) {
        setTime(time().addSecs(steps*60));
    }
    else if (currentSection() == QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection) {
        setTime(time().addSecs(steps));
    }
}
```